# Pythonic way to check if: all elements evaluate to False -OR- all elements evaluate to True

Tags: python

I want the results of the function to be:

- All values evaluate to False (None, 0, empty string) -> True
- All values evaluate to True -> True
- Every other case -> False

This is my try at it:

```
>>> def consistent(x):
...  x_filtered = filter(None, x)
...  return len(x_filtered) in (0, len(x))
...
>>> consistent((0,1))
False
>>> consistent((1,1))
True
>>> consistent((0,0))
True
```

[Bonus]

What should this function be named?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
def unanimous(it):
  it1, it2 = itertools.tee(it)
  return all(it1) or not any(it2)
```

Comment: The nice part is that one of them is guaranteed to only look at a single element.  If the first element is truthy, `any` will immediately terminate.  It it's falsy, `all` will.

Comment: the `itertools.tee` is the touch that makes this the answer worth putting in a toolkit module. You don't have to think about what you send it.

Comment: However if they mostly are truthy it will still go through almost all of them in the all(it1) call... if you used itertools.izip it would be more efficient (on average) for cases where there are mixed values.

Comment: @John: Only by one iteration, whose time would probably be chewed up by the object generation during zipping.

Comment: @John - *one* of them will have to go through all the elements, there's no getting around that.

Comment: Doh. How can I forget about `all` and `any`?

Comment: @Paul McGuire: If the lists are [t,f,t,t,t,t] and [f,t,f,f,f,f] you can stop after the second item of each list and return False.

Comment: @John - sorry for the confusion, you are right of course. I meant my comment in the case of a True condition, either all T or all F.  If all T, then the first iterator will run through the entire list and return True, and the second iterator wont even be used; if all F, then the first iterator will fail on the first element, and then the second iterator will run through the entire list and return True.

Answer (score 11):

```
def all_bools_equal(lst):
    return all(lst) or not any(lst)
```

See: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all

See: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any

Comment: beat me to it - i decided to test it first (and was just going to us a lambda

Comment: ...whoops didn't see the bonus

Comment: @Gerrat - if only StackOverflow had a Python interpreter build into the answer box ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking on Ignacio Vasquez-Abram's method, but will stop after first mismatch:

```
def unanimous(s):
  it1, it2 = itertools.tee(iter(s))
  it1.next()
  return not any(bool(a)^bool(b) for a,b in itertools.izip(it1,it2))
```

While using `not reduce(operators.xor, s)` would be simpler, it does no short-circuiting.

Comment: I was curious so I ran some tests, and surprisingly this solution is 2-3× slower than mine across a `bool` power set with 2 to 15 elements. I didn't think `itertools.izip()` would be that expensive.

Comment: I looked at yours further to really "get" what its doing. This fails mostly because so much logic is in Python, not C. I don't think a 15-element list will give you much of a test; try testing with `[1]*100000`, `[0]*100000`, `[1]*100000+[0]`, and `[0]*100000+[1]` to really see the extreme differences.  Also, I'd be curious how `not reduce(operator.xor, s)` measures up.

Comment: And even if the izip solution is much slower, it might be a better solution for cases where the input iterable is likely to be both unanimous and extremely long (perhaps produced by a generator). Here, behind the scenes, the tee only needs to store one extra element since the two tees streams are being consumed in lock step, whereas in the simpler *all or not any* solution, the second tee stream is not consumed until after the first is completely consumed so the whole sequence would need to be stored in memory if unanimous.  Perhaps both recipes belong in the toolbox!

Answer (score 2):

```
def all_equals(xs):
    x0 = next(iter(xs), False)
    return all(bool(x) == bool(x0) for x in xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so brief, but shortcuts without messing around with 'tee' or anything like that.

```
def unanimous(s):
   s = iter(s)
   if s.next():
       return all(s)
   else:
       return not any(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just yet another way of doing it, given list l:

```
sum([int(bool(x)) for x in l]) in (0, len(l))

>>> a=['',None,0,False]
>>> b=[1,True,'ddd']
>>> c=[0,1,False,True,None]
>>> for l in (a,b,c):
...  print sum([int(bool(x)) for x in l]) in (0, len(l))
... 
True
True
False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def AllTheSame(iterable):
    return any(iterable) is all(iterable)
```

Comment: -1; That's an awkward logical rearrangement (it depends on the fact that 'all' implies 'any'), and it's strange to use 'is' to compare boolean values anyway. Just stick with 'all or not any'.

Comment: The faster way was already showed by dkamins. I'm just point another  way which has its semantic. And using "is" to compare boolean values is pretty pythonic.

Comment: Disagree on the pythonicity of using "is" to compare booleans.  Use "is" to compare with singletons like None, or classes. This "is" is just a mindbender, obscuring that you are just testing for boolean equality with a supposed shortcut.

Comment: encouraging use of 'is' on bools can lead to abominations like 'if x is True:' (when what is called for is 'if x:')